# runas or sudo equivalent on AS400 ibm iSeries (invoke it via java code)

Tags: java, shell, unix-shell, ibm-midrange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“runas” or “sudo” equivalent on AS400 IBM iSeries](https://serverfault.com/questions/413451/runas-or-sudo-equivalent-on-as400-ibm-iseries)

I am trying to invoke a program to run as another user(by getting input user/pwd) in AS400 OS using Java. Like runas in windows or sudo in unix, what can we do in AS400 OS?
I am able to invoke basic unix commands like find,cd,ls etc through java on AS400. I have very restricted access on the experimental AS400 sandbox provided to me. So I am not sure if sudo command through java will work when ran as admin. 
I think on AS400 console STRQSH or QSH is a custom build program and all unix commands are not supported. Hence I am clueless about what is the correct and concert way of doing it ? Any guidance will be appreciated? How does industry folks do it? Is there any sudo/runas equivalent in AS400? Do ibm has its own shell... 
Thanks 
Akku