# "runas" or "sudo" equivalent on AS400 IBM iSeries

Tags: shell, java, ibm, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to invoke a program to run as another user (by getting input user/pwd) in AS400 OS using Java. Like `runas` in Windows or `sudo` in Unix — what can we do in AS400 OS?

I am able to invoke basic Unix commands like `find`, `cd`, `ls` etc. through Java on AS400.

I have very restricted access on the experimental AS400 sandbox provided to me. So I am not sure if `sudo` command through java will work when ran as admin.

I think on AS400 console `STRQSH` or `QSH` is a custom build program and all Unix commands are not supported. Hence I am clueless about what is the correct and concert way of doing it. Any guidance will be appreciated – how do the industry folks do it? Is there any `sudo`/`runas` equivalent in AS400? Do IBM have its own shell?

Comment: The security model on the AS400/iSeries is significantly different from Windows and Unix/Linux.  You should probably spend a little time studying it before attempting to do much with security interfaces.

Comment: Ask for a user profile that has the authorisation you need.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [QSYGETPH](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/apis/QSYGETPH.htm) api ... this will let you switch to a user profile that you have authority to.

Comment: I wanted some solution such that I don't leave the java code. After  QSYGETPH(invoke through java) we need to perform jobs with the same handle, so I cannot invoke a executable file sitting on IBM OS through java as a fresh user even after QSYGETPH api authentication is successful :(

Comment: I don't have access to  QSYGETPH but it will be great to know if we can authenticate and execute a program as a single unit. You can authenticate & execute a executable as a single unit in window or unix through java using runas/sudo (using java runtime call). How can we achieve that in IBM OS. Any strategies?

Comment: Are you trying to switch credentials in the middle of a process ... or invoke a command using different credentials from within your Java code?

Comment: invoke a command using different credentials from within your Java code.